# Not able to fetch data from Quandl in python

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, pandas, quandl

I tried the following code (written in a file test.py):

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
d=quandl.get('WIKI/PRICES')
```

And I got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\quandl\connection.py", line 55, in parse
    return response.json()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 892, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/L.Shane/Desktop/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    d=quandl.get('WIKI/PRICES')
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\quandl\get.py", line 48, in get
    data = Dataset(dataset_args['code']).data(params=kwargs, handle_column_not_found=True)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\quandl\model\dataset.py", line 47, in data
    return Data.all(**updated_options)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\quandl\operations\list.py", line 14, in all
    r = Connection.request('get', path, **options)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\quandl\connection.py", line 36, in request
    return cls.execute_request(http_verb, abs_url, **options)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\quandl\connection.py", line 44, in execute_request
    cls.handle_api_error(response)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\quandl\connection.py", line 61, in handle_api_error
    error_body = cls.parse(resp)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\quandl\connection.py", line 57, in parse
    raise QuandlError(http_status=response.status_code, http_body=response.text)
quandl.errors.quandl_error.QuandlError: (Status 403) Something went wrong. Please try again. If you continue to have problems, please contact us at connect@quandl.com.
```

How can I move forward?

UPDATE:
I also tried it in R:

```
 mydata = Quandl("WIKI/PRICES")
```

Now I got this error:

```
Error: <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Attention Required! | Cloudflare</title>

<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" id='cf_styles-ie-css' href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" /><![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">body{margin:0;padd
```

It seems like the Cloudflare Captcha is blocking (I'm not sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to pass it your authentication token:

```
quandl.get("EOD/AAPL", authtoken="...")
```

This returns the end of day prices for Apple (AAPL).

Answer (score 0):

if you are not getting data and its showing some  error when you are typing quandl.get("..."). Then You need to go to quandl. in the search  option type "GOOGLE STOCK". then click on the dataset which you opt select. After that go to library and click on the python and get something  like quandl.get(".....dataset",authtoken="....") . copy this and paste it in your command shell.